# Trying to set up RAID 1 array on existing AlmaLinux OS disk running LVM, get 'partition exists' warning

Tags: linux, lvm, mdadm, raid1

I am following instructions [from here](https://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-raid-on-existing/) for setting up a RAID1 on an existing Linux installation. The instructions are for a Debian/Ubuntu installation, but I can't find any specifically for AlmaLinux, so I am trying to adapt.

I've copied the partition set up from the original to a blank drive, and made the LVM Linux partitions "raid autodetect" using the "fdisk /dev/sdh" command.

The next step is to create new degraded RAID arrays, using `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 missing /dev/sdh1` for the two partitions (md0 and md1 for sdh1 and sbh2 respectively).

However, at this point, I get this:

```
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdh1
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sdh1 but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array?
```

... at which point I answer no.

Here's the lsblk output:

```
NAME               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                  8:0    0 476.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1               8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2               8:2    0 476.3G  0 part 
└─sda3               8:3    0   600M  0 part 
sdb                  8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1               8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sdb2               8:18   0 464.8G  0 part 
  ├─almalinux-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─almalinux-swap 253:1    0   4.4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─almalinux-home 253:2    0 390.3G  0 lvm  /home
sdc                  8:32   1     0B  0 disk 
sdd                  8:48   1     0B  0 disk 
sde                  8:64   1     0B  0 disk 
sdf                  8:80   1     0B  0 disk 
sdg                  8:96   1  57.7G  0 disk 
└─sdg1               8:97   1  57.7G  0 part /run/media/jisrael/UBUNTU DESK
sdh                  8:112  0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdh1               8:113  0     1G  0 part 
└─sdh2               8:114  0 464.8G  0 part 
sr0                 11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here's the fdisk -l output for the relevant drives:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5003ABYX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf5dec84b

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       2099200 976773119 974673920 464.8G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/sdh: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5003ABYX-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xf5dec84b

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdh1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sdh2       2099200 976773119 974673920 464.8G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-root: 70 GiB, 75161927680 bytes, 146800640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-swap: 4.43 GiB, 4752146432 bytes, 9281536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/almalinux-home: 390.33 GiB, 419115827200 bytes, 818585600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

What should I do? Thanks for any help.

Comment: These commands are **dangerous** (it destroys data irreversibly on the affected device), you should always pay **extreme attention** to what you are doing and where. Is it `sdb` or `sdh`? Also, how comes the `sdh1`, which *itself*  is the partition, contains a partition table? It doesn't work that way. If your target drive was used for something else before, maybe some garbage structures left there. // For us to give more concrete and safe advices, add `lsblk` output into the question. Also, I'd follow the advice it gives for the `/boot`: use `-e1.0` (same as `--metadata 1.0`).

Comment: It's sdh, sorry for the typo (I did enter the correct command when working on the drives). It's an LVM setup, so sdh1 has LVM partitions. So maybe this is the crux of the problem? The instructions I'm following are FOR an LVM setup, so I thought that would be factored in. I have added the lsblk to the Q.

Comment: You may only create array on devices **that are currently not used for anything**. For example, if there is a *active* VG hosted on the device, you must deactivate it first with `vgchange -n <vgname>`. If there is a *running* array, you must stop it with `mdadm --stop /dev/<mdname>`, and so on. Remove all labels from devices (`pvremove`, `mdadm --zero-superblock`, `wipefs`, etc., whatever is appropriate).

Comment: Copied? Wrong. You created problems. LVM identifies devices using UUIDs, so if it sees two devices with the same UUID, you can't be sure which one is actually used. And, when I asked `lsblk` I did not meant "only OS disk". Please, don't edit output, just append it as it is. I wanted to see the block device structure of your system, including target device and others.

Comment: Okay, apparently these instructions I'm following (at the link) are wrong. But for clarity, what I copied over was just the partition info, using `sfdisk -d /dev/sdb | sfdisk /dev/sdh` -- that wouldn't copy the UUID, would it? fdisk -l shows that the second partition is of type Linux LVM, not the first (see added info above). But the lsblk output doesn't show that.

Comment: Also, if you can point me to better instructions for this task, I'd be most grateful. That is, setting up a software RAID 1 array on an existing AlmaLinux 9.2 OS disk running LVM.

Comment: No. `sfdisk` wouldn't copy UUID of the PV, only the partition table. I thought you dd'd one devce to another. Again, you didn't answered it: was `sdh` the disk *used before* or was it clean and shiny new filled with zeros? Probably on the target disk already had a leftover MD superblock or something that made it think there is one. If you were started with *zeroing* the used device before re-using it (with e.g. `cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdh` or `pv -pterb -s <size in bytes> /dev/zero > /dev/sdh` to have a nice progress bar), there will be much less problems like this.

Comment: The how-to *in principle* is correct. But how-tos are **never** self-contained and, while it appears you can just follow it step-by-step and get the result, it isn't. There is *a lot* of documentation on the utilities used. It's like Wikipedia page: good to first learn the topic, but certainly not enough to gain expertise. This is why I am not going to recommend anything particular. You probably know it: `man mdadm`, `man lvm` and so on. Make sure you understand what's happening with the system after running each command involved in how-to.